# Nodejs & socket io : warn - error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets, websocket

I am giving a try to Node.js with socket.io

Now here is my scenario i am ubuntu 12.04 user and i have folder pp on desktop

inside that i am putted server file i.e  `app.js`

Here is the content

```
var fs = require('fs')
    , http = require('http')
    , socketio = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html'));
}).listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:8080');
});

socketio.listen(server).on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
    });
});
```

Now in the same folder i have another file index.html   like

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var iosocket = io.connect();

            iosocket.on('connect', function () {
                $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li>Connected</li>'));

                iosocket.on('message', function(message) {
                    $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text(message));
                });
                iosocket.on('disconnect', function() {
                    $('#incomingChatMessages').append('<li>Disconnected</li>');
                });
            });

            $('#outgoingChatMessage').keypress(function(event) {
                if(event.which == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    iosocket.send($('#outgoingChatMessage').val());
                    $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text($('#outgoingChatMessage').val()));
                    $('#outgoingChatMessage').val('');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Incoming Chat: <ul id="incomingChatMessages"></ul>


<input type="text" id="outgoingChatMessage">
</body>
```

when i am trying to run the app.js useing node like

```
 node app.js
```

I am getting the error

```
 warn  - error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

I go through some doc and found that port are busy so restarted the system but still i am getting the same error .

Please tell me what might i am doing wrong .

Comment: Try another port - probably `8080` is used by some other application.

Comment: i'm really having this problem, i can't find any solution.

Comment: it appears that I didn't edit the port in the server.js file, so I passed the error, but now I can't connect to it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Try another port. 8080 is usually used by tomcat e.g.

Use `netstat -a -v` to know which port are currently used.

Comment: can you print the output of `netstat -a -v` or `nmap localhost`.

Comment: nmap localhost  22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
110/tcp  open  pop3
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
143/tcp  open  imap
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Comment: I am also getting the same issue but can not see if any of the the application using this port.


Please help...

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your not connecting to the host on the client side:

```
var iosocket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

Comment: you are right but this problem is from server side if i am not wrong

Comment: instead of `res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html'));` use `readFile`

Answer (score 1):

You are not connecting to your server, this is wrong:

```
var iosocket = io.connect();
```

this is right:

```
var iosocket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

Also your port 8080 is used on your server by "http-proxy", try an other port.

Answer (score 1):

An ultra-silly/simple possibility is to make sure you don't have multiple terminal windows open. I got this error and realized I had a second pre-existing connection that I had started up my app with. When I closed it and restarted the app the error went away.

Comment: I had Putty and WinSCP open and kept getting the EADDRINUSE error; when i closed both and restarted just Putty, i was able to start node - txs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for beginners of how you can set up NodeJS + Express + SocketIO so that you have no EADDRINUSE error for the second time you start your app:

```
'use strict';

// Init
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var cors = require('cors');

// Create Server app
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);

// Socket.io settings
io.set('browser client minification', true);
io.set('browser client etag', true);
io.set('browser client gzip', true);
io.set('browser client expires', true);

// Starting Express server
server.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log(chalk.green('Server is running on localhost:' + serverPort + '...'));
});

// Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello world!");
    console.log("Root visited!");
    // Broadcast socketIO message inside Express
    io.emit('new_message', "Hello world!");
});

// Socket.io
var connections = [];
var title = "Untitled";

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.once('disconnect', () => {
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
        socket.disconnect();
        console.log('Disconnected: %s. Remained: %s.', socket.id, connections.length)
    });

    // ...

    connections.push(socket);
    console.log('Connected: %s. Total: %s', socket.id, connections.length);
});
```

I think this is a useful example and I hope it will help someone who encountered a problem setting this all up.